# How to declare @font-your-face local fonts in CSS?

Tags: theming

Pretty simple question, why does my CSS not render my fonts when I declare it programmatically (in my CSS) vs when I use the [@font-your-face](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface)  UI?

For a number of reasons I'd like to be able to control this from my styles. I'm declaring the CSS font-family declaration correctly and the text is being changed but it's going to some sort of Sans-Serif or Helvetica default.

If it matters I'm using, or trying to use omega 4.
thanks in advance.

Here's my css for the relevant selector, I know it's trying to work because the text changes but not to this font.

```
.l-page{width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family: 'Cassannet - simple';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: Just make sure the font is linked into the source, and use `font-family` as normal. There's nothing else to it, Drupal doesn't (and can't) change how the basic HTML/CSS works

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'linking the font to it's'source?

Comment: It should be something like the following: `@font-face { font-family: 'MyWebFont'; src: url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('myfont.woff') format('woff'); }`. If you are not using anything like this, it doesn't work.

Comment: in my css/sass, I assume?

Comment: It seems that the syntax is more complicated than that, any link to a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to apply the CSS in the theme in the drop down of the [@font-your-face](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface) UI.